# Passing function as a react prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I've recently started a project with a friend, now I'm trying to pass a click function of a popover from the popover component to a button component in a different place.
I know I'm suppose to pass the function as a prop and use it in the button component, but since I'm new to react and TypeScript I am having trouble doing that and I encounter a new error with every step.

```
function rand() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10;
}

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50 + rand();
  const left = 50 + rand();

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    paper: {
      position: "absolute",
      width: 400
    }
  })
);

const SimpleModal = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // getModalStyle is not a pure function, we roll the style only on the first render
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOpen}>
        a
      </button>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
          <Popover />
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail for us to be of any use. What error are you currently seeing? Is it a build error or a live console error? What have you tried so far? What is your expected behavior?

Comment: I think most of them are typescript  or declarations errors, I tried making it a prop but I think I'm not doing it right.